# is there anyway to run a thread while giving it an argument?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, concurrency

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to run a thread and give it an argument ? its like Giving an argument to that Runnable's run method , sth like

```
class Test implements Runnable 
{
     public void run( char a ) { // the question's here ,
                                 //is there any way to run a thread , 
                                 //indicating an argument for it ? 
        do  something with char a ;  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say, Yes and No.

**NO :** `run()` method defined in the Runnable interface takes no argument. Since you implement the Runnable interface, you will be implementing the `run()` method of Runnable interface, which happens to be a no-arg method.

**YES :** You can however, create overloaded method of `run()`, which can take argument. Compiler will not complain about it.  But ***remember one thing,*** this will never be called when the thread is started. It will always call the no-arg `run()` method.

e.g

```
class Test implements Runnable 
{
     public void run() {
      // ... thread's task, when it is started using .start()
      }

     // Overloaded method  : Needs to be called explicitly.
     public void run(char a) { 
      //do  something with char a ;  
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that's what i wanted to know :)

Comment: Sorry but i had another question,if we use the run method with an argument we have to call it explicitly , then how can we have some threads running from the same class ? i mean if there was just the run method in Test class  , We could have created like 10 threads operating on it like : Thread t1 = new Thread(new Test() ) Thread t2 = new Thread(new Test() ) and so on , but now , can we make some threads run simultaneously on the same class ?

Answer (score 4):

No, thats not possible, simply due to the fact, that the `Runnable` interface has no argument for the `run` method. You could assign the value to a member-variable of the Thread and use it:

```
class Test implements Runnable 
{
     private final char a;

     public Test(char a) {
         this.a  = a;
     }

     public void run() {
       // do  something with char a ;  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Runnable.run()` method does not take any arguments, and you can't change that.  But there are ways to pass input to and return output from a Thread.  For instance:

```
public int someMethod(final int arg) throws InterruptedException {
    final int[] result = new int[1];
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            result[0] = arg * arg;
        }
    });
    t.start();
    // do something else
    t.join();
    return result[0];
}
```

Note that the `run()` method can only refer to `final` variables of the enclosing method, but those variables can be references to mutable objects; e.g. the `int[]`.

A variation of this is to use instance variables of the enclosing Class.

Alternatively, you can create a subclass of `Thread`, implement its `run()` method, and use constructor arguments, getters and/or setters to pass arguments and results.